# line 15: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration-files

When I try to start my ark server made with [lgsm](https://docs.linuxgsm.com/game-servers/ark-survival-evolved) it states the following error:

```
arkserver@ark-HP-Compaq-Elite-8300-SFF:~$ ./arkserver start
/home/arkserver/lgsm/config-lgsm/arkserver/arkserver.cfg: line 15: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/home/arkserver/lgsm/config-lgsm/arkserver/arkserver.cfg: line 17: syntax error: unexpected end of file
[ .... ] Starting arkserver: LinuxGSM./arkserver: eval: line 494: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `}'
./arkserver: eval: line 495: syntax error: unexpected end of file
[  OK  ] Starting arkserver: LinuxGSM
arkserver@ark-HP-Compaq-Elite-8300-SFF:~$
```

this is the cfg file:

```
##################################
####### Instance Settings ########
##################################
# PLACE INSTANCE SETTINGS HERE
## These settings will apply to a specific instance.

port="7777"
queryport="27015"
# Default Map: TheIsland, Scorched Earth_P, Aberration_P, Extinction, Genesis, TheCenter, Ragnarok, CrystalIsles, Valguero_P, Fjordur
instancename="ETA-Season-1"
defaultmap="Fjordur"
maxplayers="4"
## Server Start Command
fn_parms(){
parms="\"${defaultmap}?AltSaveDirectoryName=${instancename}?listen?MultiHome=${ip}?MaxPlayers=${maxplayers}?QueryPort=${queryport)?RCONPort=${rconport}?Port=${port} -automanagedmods -exclusivejoin -NoBattlEye -usecache -insecure -noantispeedhack \""
}
```

I tried changing the quotation marks around on line 15 but it just gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `queryport)` to `queryport}` in line 15.

That fixed it for me.